# How to add custom UIView(xib) in custom UITableviewCell with the help of AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

I have one View Controller in which I have one `UITableView`.

I have used custom `UITableviewCell` with xib in that `UITableView`.

Now I have one `UIView` with xib and I want to add that `UIView's` object in custom `UITableViewCell` with the help of AutoLayout.

I added that `UIView` successfully in custom `UITableViewCell`, but that `UIView` is so much **big** and **it is not fitting in my custom** `UITableViewCell`.

I know that `UIView` can be fit properly in custom `UITableViewCell` with the help of AutoLayout, but I don't know How, because I am new to AutoLayout.

In My Custom `UITableViewCell`

```
CustomAlertCell.m//this is my custom UITableViewCell class

-(void)addCustomView_ForRow:(int)theRow
{
    JobAlertCell_View *vwJob = [[JobAlertCell_View alloc] initFromNibFile:@"JobAlertCell_View"];
   vwJob.frame = CGRectMake(0, 118, vwJob.frame.size.width, vwJob.frame.size.height);
   [self addSubview:vwJob];
}
```

Here my `vwJob.frame.size.height = 90`, but in device it is much bigger that the size i want.

Thanks.

Comment: are the dimensions of your `UIView` variable ?

Comment: Nope, my Custom UIVIew's height and width are fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add width and height constraint using below code

```
    -(void)addCustomView_ForRow:(int)theRow
    {
       JobAlertCell_View *vwJob = [[JobAlertCell_View alloc] initFromNibFile:@"JobAlertCell_View"];
       [self addSubview:vwJob];

        [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:vwJob
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:nil
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                      multiplier:1.0
                                                        constant:100.0]];
        [self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:vwJob
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem:nil
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                      multiplier:1.0
                                                        constant:100.0]];
        [self layoutIfNeeded];

    }
```

**Source:**

https://codehappily.wordpress.com/2013/09/21/constant-height-width-constraint-autolayout/
https://codehappily.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/ios-how-to-programmatically-add-auto-layout-constraints-for-a-view-that-will-fit-its-superview/

Hope it helps you...!

Comment: I tried your code but still same issue. I am getting below warning.Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
 Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want."<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb260c9faf0 H:[JobAlertCell_View:0x7fb260ca00b0(100)]>",<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fb260d50040 h=-&- v=-&- JobAlertCell_View:0x7fb260ca00b0.width == JobAlert_Cell:0x7fb260c973c0.width>,<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fb260d510d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[JobAlert_Cell:0x7fb260c973c0(320)]>

Comment: Remove width constraint from above code. And also change constant values as per your need..of height constraint..!

Comment: It worked but I didn't remove width constraint, but I wrote     [vwJob setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO]; before setting my constraints. But now problem is that my custom UIView always starts from x=0 and y=0, but i want different origins of my custom UIView

Comment: I did it. this link is helpful: https://codehappily.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/ios-how-to-programmatically-add-auto-layout-constraints-for-a-view-that-will-fit-its-superview/

Comment: Accept it as answer if it is useful to you..@NiravPatel. Above link is useful to fix ur issue..!